# Scheme alternative for muliple themes in iOS app

Tags: ios, architecture

I have a code base thats shared by multiple brands. A single ios project ideally has around 3 schemes - debug, acceptance and production to enable easy switching of endpoints and some additional configuration.

Problem at hand is that the same code base is shared by a couple of brands and although the endpoints for the brands are same the AppNames, Icons and themes should be different. 
This can be done with having individual schemes for each brand, but this results in a really messy setup.

With each brand having its own schemes , 3 schemes for each environment result in 15 schemes for 5 brands which is not elegant at all.
What can be a more elegant way to handle this - in xcode or with any other tools.

Comment: Each app is a new target though, right?

Comment: If thats an option? The problem is to create different apps from the same code base that have different Icons, names and signing